# How to make microservices communicate with each other?

Tags: laravel, microservices

I have two services: 1.Accounting Service 2.Chat Service. I want them to communicate with each other. For example on Accounting Service, there is a button 'Chat'. On click of that button, I want to call the Chat Service. How to make this happen? Do I need to create an API Gateway? If yes, how to create it?

Comment: That's a very broad and subjective question. Also not clear if you're asking "how" or "how-best". It might help to make your questions here a little more pointed. "Can someone explain the Gateway Pattern and when it's appropriate to use", or "what Adapter packages are out there to ease communication between services". SO is better suited for specifics, rather than opinion-based group-architecture conversations.

Comment: From your example it's not clear whether you want to communicate between two services or want to request across multiple services from a frontend app/service.